# transform '#ff00fffirstword#445533secondword#008877thirdword' to html tag format

Tags: javascript, regex

Can I transform string `#ff00fffirstword#445533secondword#008877thirdword` to

```
<font color='#ff00ff'>firstword</font><font color='#445533'>secondword</font><font color='#008877'>thirdword</font>
```

Using regexp in javascript or actionscript3 program?

I tried the code below, but it's not perfect (actionscript3 code):

```
var pat:RegExp = /(#\w{6})([^#]+)/g;
var html:String = t.replace(pat, "<font color=\'$1\'>$2</font>");
trace(html); // output :<font color='#ff00ff'>firstword</font><font color='#445533'>secondword</font><font color='#008877'>thirdword</font>
```

If there one more `#` in that string, the output would not be like I want it to be. I don't know how to write a stronger regexp to achieve this.

Comment: As an aside, `font` tag is deprecated and isn't guaranteed to work in the future. It's best practice to use CSS instead, e.g. `<span style="color: #ABCDEF">...</span>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using an `or` (`|`) operator and a lookahead for the end of line:

```
var pat:RegExp = /(#[0-9a-f]{6})([^#]+?)(?=#|$)/gi;
var html:String = t.replace(pat, "<font color=\'$1\'>$2</font>");
trace(html);
```

I would also personally use `[0-9a-f]` instead of `\w` here just in case. The lookahead `(?=#|$)` ensures that it's the end of line or another hash. I also inserted the `i` flag just in case as well.

Since you also have stray hashes, you can use this one:

```
var pat:RegExp = /(#[0-9a-f]{6})(.+?)(?=#[0-9a-f]{6}|$)/gi;
var html:String = t.replace(pat, "<font color=\'$1\'>$2</font>");
trace(html);
```

See the output [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/nO9zS5).

And the debuggex:

[image: Regular expression image]

Comment: if source string be '#ff00fffirstword#445533secondword##008877thi#rdword#' the output should be <font color='#ff00ff'>firstword</font><font color='#445533'>secondword#</font><font color='#008877'>thi#rdword#</font>

Comment: @RexSmith Added a new regex to care for that! I didn't know you also have stray hashes, so that should be working now :)

Answer (score 6):

## Description

You could use this regex

Regex:  `([#][0-9a-f]{6})(.*?)(?=[#]|$)`
Replace with `<font color='\1'>\2</font>`

[image]

## Javascript Code Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var re = /([#][0-9a-f]{6})(.*?)(?=[#]|$)/;
  var sourcestring = "#ff00fffirstword#445533secondword#008877thirdword";
  var replacementpattern = "<font color='\1'>\2</font>";
  var result = sourcestring.replace(re, replacementpattern);
  alert("result = " + result);
</script>

$sourcestring after replacement:
<font color='#ff00ff'>firstword</font><font color='#445533'>secondword</font><font color='#008877'>thirdword</font>
```

Comment: How did you generate the regex flow diagram ?

Comment: Shouldn't `sourcestring` be `#ff00fffirstword#445533secondword#008877thirdword`?

Comment: @ Jordan Trudgett & Rex Smith: Yep, already corrected, please refresh your browser.

Comment: sourcestring = '#ff00fffirstword#445533secondword#008877thirdword';

Comment: @ DhruvPathak, Crayola! hahaha. But seriously I'm using debuggex.com . Although it doesn't support lookbehinds or atomic groups it's still handy for understanding the expression flow. There is also regexper.com. They do a pretty good job too, but it's not real time as you're typing.